# c# regular expression match even-parenthesis in expression

Tags: c#, expression, parentheses

I have the following expressions:

```
KNOWN_TOKEN=((value operator value) operator value) 
            operator OTHER_KNOWN_TOKEN=value 
            operator KNOWN_TOKEN2=(value operator (value operator value));
```

I am trying to find a c# regular expression to return me the entire expression with equally matched closed parenthesis as they were opened. This means, for `KNOWN_TOKEN` I need only `((value operator value) operator value)`, for `OTHER_KNOWN_TOKEN` I need only `value` and for `KNOWN_TOKEN2` I need `(value operator (value operator value))`.

I tried various flavours of `(\([^(]+\))` but they only match the 'lowest' set of 'paranthesis' and in addition, they match an extra one (i.e. for `KNOWN_TOKEN2` they match an extra ending parenthesis).

Also, I have found some hints on the web on doing it into several repeating steps and alter the original text, but I'd rather do it into one single regexp. Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: I I'm not that deep into the RegEx used here (I think they can to a form of backtracking) but a theoretical regex (the ones that are equivalent to  finite-automata) cannot do such a thing and I guess if you use RegEx for this purpose it might get rather slow. Have thought about making a simple parser for that?

Comment: I actually started this 'backup' solution but I thought there's an elegant solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<token>[^=]*)=(?<value>\(*value.*)");
foreach (Match item in reg.Matches(""))
{
      var token= item.Groups["token"].Value.Trim();
      var val= item.Groups["value"].Value.Trim(';');
}
```

**EDITED**

Comment: are you sure that this one is doing it's job? RegexTester says no - even if I change value to \w+ (the last one) it will match as many opening or closing brackets I put in there ... I don't think this is a valid solution

Comment: Yes i have some error. But his main goal is `Value` not token. Correct is `(?<attrib>[^=]*)=(?<value>\(*value.*)`

Comment: I don't think that value stands for "value" but for a Token-Symbol like 3 or 3.4 or whatever - and still the last part of your regex matches "(value 3)" as well as "(value 3))" and he want's to "count" the brackets

Comment: value it's a simple token/keyword. Can be an integer or a simple word (but I don't know which one). I think Carsten Konig it's right - there's no reliable way to extract a subexpression from a bigger string and to match the number of opened parenthesis using regular expressions. Will stick to the more conventional way.

Comment: Probably you should add your original comment as a response and to mark this question as answered.